# Task "Fody.weavingTask" failed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This is my first question on Stack Overflow. I'm sorry for my English and apologize in advance if I missed some rule.

I'm a beginner in C# and I have a project that I modified. When I debug the solution I have this error:

> Echec inattendu de la la tache `Fody.weavingTask`.

Translation:

> Task `Fody.weavingTask` failed unexpectedly.

Can you help please?

Comment: What is the inner exception?

Comment: To get better help, I recommend using https://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Emt.aspx to translate your error message to English. Not only will there be much more people on SO that understands the error message and thus how to troubleshoot, but it'll also be much easier to get good search results!

Comment: After guessing a couple of times on which language this is, I found the french translation "The task failed unexpectedly `Fody.weavingTask`".

Comment: Did you install the `Fody` nuget package?

Comment: Looks like you are missing `Fody` nuget package - restore all nuget packages and see if this works.

Comment: thank you for your response sir, how can i install the Fody nuget package? i'm not so good with c# and i'm lost.